# Form fields | Django | ModelChoiceField

Tags: python, django, forms

i can't find answer for my problem, so i ask you guys here.
I'm trying make form with ModelChoiceField, all works (no error given) but still don't get any fields/options (blank Choice) and can't choose something. 
Here is my code

models.py

```
class Search(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=30)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
  def label_from_instance(self, obj):
    return "My Object #%i" % obj.id

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
  search_text = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
  wybor = MyModelChoiceField(queryset= Search.objects.all())
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def label_from_instance(obj):
    return "My Object #%i" % obj.id

self.fields['wybor'].label_from_instance = label_from_instance
```

Comment: I got this: NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you have data in your Search table. To test try this view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.forms import ModelChoiceField
from django import forms
from models import Search


class MyModelChoiceField(ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        return "My Object #%i" % obj.id

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    search_text = forms.CharField(max_length=50)
    wybor = MyModelChoiceField(queryset=Search.objects.all())


def test_view(request):

    f = SearchForm()

    ids = Search.objects.values_list('id', flat=True)

    return render(request, 'yourapp/test.html',
                      {
                          'form': f,
                          'ids': ids
                      })
```

test.html template:

```
{{ form }}

<br/>

search ids:

{{ ids }}
```

in html output you should see search ids:

```
search ids: [1, 2, ...]
```

Comment: Hey, only what i've got is:  search ids: []

Comment: So it means your table is empty... try to add some data :)

Comment: Like i answer 18hours before, i found other solution in documentation :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i think i've got this.
I found this in documentation:

```
from django.db import models

class Person(models.Model):
SHIRT_SIZES = (
    ('S', 'Small'),
    ('M', 'Medium'),
    ('L', 'Large'),
)
name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
shirt_size = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SHIRT_SIZES)
```

And it's working (display) and a form is valid :) I hope this will be working at the next steps.